# html Input Button onclick=display:None

Tags: html, css, button, sharepoint-2010

I placed a html button on my page and I want to hide or show a control. but following code is not working

```
<input type="button" name="Button1" value="Show/Hide Phonetics Search" onclick="document.getElementByID('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7').style.display='none';" style="width: 225px; height: 40px;"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `getElementById` (lower-case `d`, case-sensitive).

http://jsfiddle.net/nnNzC/

Comment: Can you paste full codes. May be something missing?

Answer (score 0):

"Id" is case sensitive. "ID" will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Replace  onclick="document.getElementByI`D`.. with  onclick="document.getElementByI`d`..

Refer **[this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)** for Document getElementById() Method

Comment: How you define `MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementById` not `getElementByID`.
Try this to hide/show an object (For example, a label): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxVQU/)